# Excel/Sheets adding and listing cell values based on adjacent cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm having trouble working on a formula for a spreadsheet.

My sheet has multiple lists of items, and each item in each list has an inconsistent dollar value, like so:

[image]

I'd like to create another section in the sheet to display info about the items, irrespective of the list they're in. Specifically, I need the total value per item, and each item's percent of the total, like so:

[image]

I'm not sure how to accomplish this with a formula. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `SUMIF()` should be able to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**cell D2:**

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>""))
```

**cell E2 (then drag down):**

```
=SUM(FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE($B$2:$B)), $A$2:$A=D2))
```

**cell F2 (then drag down):**

```
=TEXT(E2/SUM($E$2:$E),"#.#0%")
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

for finding the total value and percent of total are the same in either excel or google sheets.
for the total value use `=sumif([range.sourceItems],[summary.item],[range.sourceValue])`
for the percent of total use `=[summary.totalValue]/sum([range.sourceValue])`

if you're going to use google sheets for your final solution, you can even use `=unique([range.sourceItems])` to dynamically manage your list of items in your summary table.

see [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gdhnl34HKqvqN33xnoKd3xuChE_XQL2DDWonTm9UgNU/edit?usp=sharing) for an example.

Comment: Thanks! player0's answer was more helpful, but yours also helped.